# Japanese idiom for don't let it get to your head?

Tags: idioms, english-to-japanese

In the sense of "don't be arrogant".

Comment: You give two data points: "don't let it get to your head" and "don't be arrogant". To me, they aren't really interchangeable and your question doesn't contain any other clues as to what you really want to ask, so maybe you could elaborate.

Comment: The phrase the OPs means might not be "don't let it *get* to your head", but rather "don't let it *go* to your head".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can say:

- うぬぼれるな
- 調子に乗るな
- 思い上がるな
- いい気になるな

If you need an *idiom*, you can also say 天狗になるな (lit. "Don't become a *tengu*").

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tengu):

> The tengu of this period were often conceived of as the ghosts of the arrogant, and as a result the creatures have become strongly associated with vanity and pride. Today the Japanese expression *tengu ni naru* ("becoming a tengu") is still used to describe a conceited person.

Comment: ああ、ありがとう。 なるとさんの日本語は上手ですね。だが,天狗にならないでね!

Comment: @Rascalniikov narutoさんはネイティブなんですけど…。